# How to remove relationship in Neo4jRB 3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

I have two models:

```
class Topic 
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  has_many :in, :favorited_by, model_class: User, origin: :favorite_topics
end
```

and

```
class User 
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  has_many :out, :favorite_topics, model_class: Topic, type: 'favorited_by'
end
```

How I can remove only association?

```
irb(main):008:0> Topic.first.favorited_by.delete(User.first)
NoMethodError: undefined method `delete' for #<Neo4j::ActiveNode::Query::QueryProxy:0x00000004b27f10>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry for my first answer, I thought it was a has_many assocation.  This works, but it's not ideal:

```
topic = Topic.first
user = User.first
topic.favorited_by = topic.favorited_by.to_a - [user]
```

EDIT:

```
topic.favorited_by(:user, :rel).match_to(user).delete_all(:rel)
```

This is a bit better, but still not great.  I just created a github issue for this:

https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/issues/630

Comment: Also, FYI check out the issue.  @subvertallchris put together a solution in master

Answer (score 3):

Piggybacking on Brian's comment, you can do `Topic.first.favorited_by.first_rel_to(User.delete).destroy` if you're running the latest release, 4.0.0.rc.1, and know that you only have one relationship between the two.

If you're using the master branch from Github, I just added `delete` and `destroy` methods to QueryProxy. `Topic.first.favorited_by.delete(User.first)` will run from the database, `Topic.first.favorited_by.destroy(User.first)` will return the relationship to Ruby and call delete, triggering callbacks. These will be will in the next release, which should be soon.